# Why does C++11 not support 'std::function<void(int, ...)>'?

Tags: c++, function, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

```
#include <functional>

void f1(int)
{}

void f2(int, ...)
{}

int main()
{
    std::function<void(int)>      g1 = f1; // OK.
    std::function<void(int, ...)> g2 = f2; // Error! Not standard C++!
}
```

Why does C++11 not provide a specialized template class as follows:

```
template<class ResultType, class... ArgTypes>
class function<ResultType(ArgTypes......)>
{
    // ... ... ...
};
```

Comment: Have you tested a template that looks like that to see if it would work?

Comment: Both of your snippets show completely different things. Variadic templates are handled at compile time. The "C" style variable arguments are handled at runtime.

Comment: The `...` (not in the variadic template) parameter syntax is retained for backward compatibility with C. Its usage is highly discouraged.

Comment: @MarkGarcia: It is not deprecated, as far as the C++ specification is concerned. It's simply suggested that people not use it unless they really need it.

Comment: @NicolBolas OK. Rephrased the comment.

Comment: The biggest technical obstacle IMO is that variadic argument lists (I mean the ellipses here) cannot be forwarded. This makes type erasure quite difficult to get done.

Comment: @mfontanini: The actual processing of the arguments *inside* a variadic function is done at runtime, but I think the compiler must know what objects (and their types) are present at the time of the function call.

Comment: @Andy: They sure can be forwarded.  See `vprintf`.  But that requires help from the callee.

Comment: You would have to have a special `make_vararg_function` function to do this. And even then it wouldn't be a standard `function` object because its arguments wouldn't be known at compile time. You have to make it freely assignable to any match `function` object for convenience's sake though. It would be a royal pain.

Comment: Great question with a great answer!

Answer (score 5):

I do not mean to provide the ultimate reason why that specialization is not provided (I do not know that), but maybe I could hint at some of the technical obstacles that could be encountered when trying to implement it. That will hopefully give you a feeling of why the specialization is not there.

Let's consider first how the `std::function<>` class template itself could be implemented. The type erasure technique that underlies its design could be sketched as follows (this is just an illustrative *simplification*, the real implementation is way more complex):

```
#include <memory>

template<typename T>
struct function { };

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct function<R(Args...)>
{

public:

    template<typename F>
    function(F&& f) : _holder(
        new holder<typename std::decay<F>::type>(std::forward<F>(f))
        )
    { }

    R operator () (Args&&... args)
    { _holder->call(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }

private:

    struct holder_base
    { virtual R call(Args&&... args) = 0; };

    template<typename F>
    struct holder : holder_base
    {
        holder(F&& f) : _f(std::forward<F>(f)) { }
        R call(Args&&... args) { return _f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }
        F _f;
    };

    std::unique_ptr<holder_base> _holder;
};
```

Now let's see how the specialization for ellipses would look like. First of all, the number and type of the arguments provided to a variadic function is *not* fixed in that function's signature. Therefore, the call operator of our specialized template must be a function template accepting any number and type of arguments:

```
template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct function<R(Args.......)>
{
    ...

    template<typename... Ts>
    R operator () (Args&&... args, Ts&&... ts)
    { _holder->call(std::forward<Args>(args)..., std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); }

    ...
```

This forces us, in turn, to make `holder<>`'s call operator a variadic function template. However, in order to realize type erasure, that same call operator must be `virtual`, and function templates cannot be `virtual` in C++.

Things would certainly be easier if variadic arguments (I'm talking about ellipses here) could be easily forwarded without having to recur to variadic template parameters and perfect forwarding. I am not aware of a simple way to achieve that though, and especially not if no other argument is to be passed to the function than those matching the variadic list.

Comment: I think there are some other approaches you could take. But yeah, the technical challenges of implementing it make my head hurt, and I'm not sure it could be done at all cleanly.

Comment: You *might* try to pass a `va_args` object to the virtual `operator()(Args..., va_args vargs)`, and then try to somehow expand that in the `holder`'s `operator()`... but I think that would be mighty messy.